# name already used by an existing constraint

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Create Table Resources_user
(
Resources_userID             INTEGER NOT NULL,
Resources_ID                  INTEGER NOT NULL,
User_ID                       INTEGER NOT NULL,
Data Accessed                             DATE,
CONSTRAINT PK_Resources_user  PRIMARY KEY (Resources_userID),
constraint fk_Resources_user1  Foreign key  (Resources_ID ) references Resources,
constraint fk_Resources_user2  Foreign key  (User_ID) references User1);


Create table Staff_Position
(
Staff_Position_ID  INTEGER NOT NULL,
Position_ID         INTEGER NOT NULL,
User_ID             INTEGER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Staff_Position PRIMARY KEY (Staff_Position_ID),
Constraint fk_Staff_Position1 foreign key (Position_ID) references position,
Constraint fk_Staff_Position2 foreign key (User_ID) references User1);
```

Thank you the problem been solved, I realized that i need to number my foreign keys for avoiding the error of repeating .

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Please check for spaces in your _DDL_ after `PK_`

Answer (score 3):

Your foreign key constraints are incomplete.  You did not specify a field.  This:

```
, constraint fk_Resources_user Foreign key (Resources_ID ) references Resources
```

should be something like this:

```
, constraint fk_Resources_user Foreign key (Resources_ID ) 
references Resources (resources_id)
```

Some Oracle error messages are misleading.  This is one of them.

**Edit Starts Here**

You also have duplicate constraint names for your foreign keys.  You will likely get a message indicating such once the other problems are resolved.

Comment: Im still receiving the same error!

Comment: Edit your question to show your latest attempt with only one of the tables.  Make sure to add 4 spaces at the start of each line so that the code appears as such.